Отслеживание бездействия на планшете
На пк весрии я могу отследить бездействия пользователя следующим способом
document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetTimer);
  document.addEventListener('keypress', resetTimer);
  function resetTimer() {
    console.log(1);
    clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(fn, 60000)
  }

но на планшете (мобильная версия хрома) этот способ не запускается, подскажите, каким ивентом это отслеживать?

touchstart например?

У вас на ПК нет "лагов" в работе с такой реализацией слушателей?

Надеюсь у вас на сайте нет просмотра видео, потому что просмотр тоже считается как за действие

@SwaD нет проблем, все работает как надо.

нет, видео нет, спасибо @EzioMercer
